# checking kafka data if compressed

Tags: apache-kafka

The document said add the line `compression.codec=gzip` in producer.properties to make the message compressed. 

However when I open the data file such as: `0000000000000.log` I found the data does not look like it is compressed. How should check whether the data in kafka is compressed already?
P.S: Every testing I would stop the Kafka cluster and Zookeeper and deleted all of the data in kafka-logs and Zookeeper,then start the server again and create a new topic.

Comment: What `KafkaProducer` client and version are you using?

Comment: @chrsblck I'm using kafka_2.10-0.8.2.1 and I just used command line bin/kafka-console-producer.sh to test the producer.

Answer (score 3):

The Java `ProducerConfig` class has changed for this config.

```
public static final String COMPRESSION_TYPE_CONFIG = "compression.type";
```

I've successfully produced messages with the java client (`0.8.2.1`) using the `ProducerConfig.COMPRESSION_TYPE_CONFIG` and it works fine.

Example:

```
props.put(ProducerConfig.COMPRESSION_TYPE_CONFIG, "gzip");
```

Or set `compression.type=gzip` in your `server.properties` file for the Java client.

**Update for cli tool**

Read the usage for the command line tools:

```
chrisblack:kafka:% ./bin/kafka-console-producer.sh 
...
--compression-codec [compression-codec] The compression codec: either 'none',
                                          'gzip', 'snappy', or 'lz4'.If
                                          specified without value, then it
                                          defaults to 'gzip'
...
--new-producer                          Use the new producer implementation.
--producer-property <producer_prop>     A mechanism to pass user-defined
                                          properties in the form key=value to
                                          the producer.
--property <prop>                       A mechanism to pass user-defined
                                          properties in the form key=value to
                                          the message reader. This allows
                                          custom configuration for a user-
                                          defined message reader.
...
```

Try running a similar command from the shell:

```
./bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic test_compression --compression-codec
```

Comment: I just tried your suggestion and restarted the cluster, but it seems the messages still not were compressed, I past the data in 00000000000000000000.log file: ^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@=ÛþC<95>^@^@ÿÿÿÿ^@^@^@/this is just a message to test if the config works^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^A^@^@^@^T

Comment: I still could see the original message: "this is just a message to test if the config works". So is the data were compressed please.

Comment: this is the new topic. Before testing I deleted all of the topics.

Comment: @Jack can you update your question with the exact steps to replicate?

Comment: Thanks Chrsblck, I add P.S

Comment: @Jack I've update the answer to include `kafka-console-producer.sh` usage.